# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python-3.x, http, twitter, twython

I am trying to crawl Twitter with Twython, tweepy module according to their documentation. Each time  got stuck along with max entries restrictions:

```
#python 3.8.2
#twython 3.8.2

from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,
              OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitter.verify_credentials(verify = False)
twitter.get_home_timeline()
```

Error

*twython.exceptions.TwythonError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/account/verify_credentials.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa1b4d86100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))*

Any suggestions What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error simply because twitter is filtered/prohibited in your area !
try connecting with proxy !